# Which method is equivalent to url_for on Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any method equivalent to [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)/[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)’s `url_for` on [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/)?  Express.js seems to provide the router, but I cannot find its opposite function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method, because Express is more lightweight and doesn't have an MVC structure by default, as neither does Sinatra (Express was inspired by Sinatra).